# Discrepancies in basic strength of different amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

The order of basic strength of ethyl substituted amines is

$\ce{(C2H5)2NH}$ > $\ce{(C2H5)3N}$ > $\ce{(C2H5)NH2}$ > $\ce{NH3}$

Which means secondary amine is more basic than tertiary followed by primary and then ammonia.

But the order of basic strength of methyl substituted amines is

$\ce{(CH3)2NH}$ > $\ce{(CH3)NH2}$ > $\ce{(CH3)3N}$ > $\ce{NH3}$

Here the tertiary amine is less basic than primary amine.

What is the reason behind this discrepancy.

Comment: Review also search results for [site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org relative basicity of alkyl substituted ammonia](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Alibretexts.org+relative+basicity+of+alkyl+substituted+ammonia)

Comment: These differences are so tiny, you can call all these compounds equally strong. Another thing is considering pKa values some kind of universal truth about acidity. All these values have uncertainties and are appropriate only for diluted aq. solutions.